# Trying to run TableToTable tool to export view from SQL server database to enterprise SDE in standalone Python script

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, error-000732

I’m trying to export a view from an SDE connection to a SQL server database to new table in an enterprise SDE database.

Both are saved as SDE connection files on a file share.

I’m getting

> ERROR 000732: Input Rows: Dataset \ \ \Connection to SQLServerDatabse.sde\GIS.GIS_PIN_INFO does not exist or is not supported.

This happens for both SDE connection file paths.

Workspace is set to enterprise SDE connection using same sde connection file path.

I’m very new to Python.

```
Import arcpy

Arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Variables

in_rows = r"\\machineName\filePath\Connection to SQLServer.sde\GIS_PIN_INFO"
out_path = r"\\machineName\filePath\Connection to EnterpriseSDE.sde"
out_table = "GIS_Info"

arcpy.conversion.TableToTable(in_rows, out_path, out_table)
```

Comment: How are you distinguishing between "SQL Server database" and "Enterprise SDE database"? Note that Python doesn't accept the UTF-8 directional quote as one of the quote characters. Do you really have a leading space in the `out_path` variable?

Comment: Vince, the sql server db and enterprise sde db are both saved as connection files in a file share. I have read access to the SQL db as it's managed by another department. The enterprise db I have read/write access to. The space was a typo on my part.

Comment: Is the view literally "viewName" (mixed case)? Because ArcGIS doesn't support mixed-case names.

Comment: No I just put that as a placeholder. The view name is GIS_PIN_INFO. For reference, I've run this as a model in model builder and it worked, referencing the same connection files as the code above.